# Mypy: importing standard libary module from module with the same name

Tags: python, import, mypy, absolute-path

For a new application, I want to set up logging.  The app is going to contain several modules, that will require the same kind of configuration.  So I create a module `my_company/logging.py`:

```py
import logging  # the standard Python logging

def configure():
  logging.getLogger('module1').setLevel(logging.INFO)
  logging.getLogger('module2').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

`mypy` does not really like this:

```
my_company/logging.py:6: error: Module has no attribute "getLogger"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 3 source files)
```

How can I make mypy see that it should use the `logging` module python distribution, not from the `my_company` folder?

Comment: have you tried something like `import logging as lg`?

Comment: Thansl - I did, to no avail :(

Comment: How do you use ``my_company/logging.py``? As the name implies, it should be ``my_company.logger`` which would not clash with ``logging``. Be aware that you cannot generally have two modules of the *exact* same name, since modules are application-global.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi indeed.  My only problem is with `mypy` trying to use _my_ logging module.  I was hoping something was wrong with my code, but maybe it's my mypy.

Comment: Again, how do you use `my_company/logging.py`? A naive reconstruction does *not* reproduce the error for me. Please provide a [mcve] – the minimum number of files, their content, how they are arranged and how mypy is run.

Comment: :( problem disappeared for a while.  I'll be back when it reappears.

Comment: Hey @xtofl did you try the solution by Cesar below? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69852452/110395

It really seems to be the missing __init__.py as I also had the same problem and it's easily reproducible if you omit the __init__.py from the directory where the module which shadows the built-in module resides.

Comment: @Lefteris I must have done 'something' to make it go away, and I don't remember what.  So I didn't consciously try it.  I did take a habit, however, to avoid choosing module names that are in the standard library already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It could be a namespaced package problem

I had exactly the same problem and it was caused by a missing `__init__.py` file.

Adding it fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly the answer the OP was probably looking for. I stumbled upon the question having the same problem with mypy and your hint helped me solve it.

Comment: Namespace packages rock; support for them is not yet great, though :).

Comment: Where was the file missing? In the custom package? Somewhere else?